# .Net Unit Testing the UTC and local time difference

Tags: .net, unit-testing, datetime, utc

I am trying to unit test the following method:

```
Public Shared Function GetLocalTimeWithTimeDifferenceUTC(startTime As DateTime) As String
    Dim localTime As String = ""
    Dim timeUTC As DateTime = startTime.ToUniversalTime()
    Dim timeDiff As TimeSpan = startTime.Subtract(timeUTC)
    Dim sSign As String = "+"
    If timeDiff.TotalMinutes < 0 Then
        sSign = "-"
        timeDiff = timeDiff.Negate
    End If
    Dim offsetUTC As String = sSign & String.Format("{0:d2}:{1:d2}", timeDiff.Hours, timeDiff.Minutes)
    localTime = startTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss") & offsetUTC

    Return localTime
End Function
```

It returns (for example startTime = 2015,3,18,10,0,0 time difference is plus two hours) 2015-03-18T10:00:00+02:00.

Here is my unit test:

```
Public Sub GetLocalTimeWithTimeDifferenceUTC_Test()
        Dim expected As String
        Dim actual As String
        Dim param As New System.DateTime(2015, 3, 5, 10, 0, 0)
        expected = "2015-03-05T10:00:00+03:00"
        Using (ShimsContext.Create())
            System.Fakes.ShimDateTime.NowGet = Function() As System.DateTime
                                                   Return New DateTime(2015, 3, 5, 10, 0, 0)
                                               End Function
            System.Fakes.ShimDateTime.UtcNowGet = Function() As System.DateTime
                                                      Return New DateTime(2015, 3, 5, 7, 0, 0)
                                                  End Function
            actual = StringFunctions.GetLocalTimeWithTimeDifferenceUTC(param)
        End Using
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual)
    End Sub
```

The changes that I apply to DateTime.Now and DateTime.UtcNow don't work and the test fails. When I try with my real localtime, it works. Is it possible that to be caused of function ToUniversalTime()? Should I change something in my approach? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't shown any code anywhere which calls `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.UtcNow`. Is `GetLocalStartTime` meant to do that? You haven't shown that code - only `GetLocalTimeWithTimeDifferenceUTC`. As an aside, all of this is pretty nasty - if you want a local time with an offset from UTC, that's what the `DateTimeOffset` type is for...

Comment: Oh, GetLocalStartTime is GetLocalTimeWithTimeDifferenceUTC, a typo error, I changed it now. I assume that ToUniversalTime() uses DateTime.Now and DateTime.UtcNow. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, why would `ToUniversalTime` do anything with `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.UtcNow`? It's called on a specific DateTime...

Comment: I thought ToUniversalTime uses DateTime.Now and DateTime.UtcNow in order to calculate the time difference.

Comment: No, because that wouldn't work when the UTC offset changes over time. Imagine you're in a country with daylight saving time, so that in winter the UTC offset is +2, and in summer it's +3. If you call `GetLocalTimeWithDifferenceUTC` passing in a summer time, and it happens to be winter, you wouldn't want it to report the winter offset with the summer time...

Comment: Note that if you just used DateTimeOffset everywhere, this wouldn't be a problem. Or if you used something like Noda Time's ZonedDateTime which keeps the time zone around as well. Otherwise you're relying on the system time zone, which you'd *also* potentially want to fake out, leading to a horrible mess.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: So I have to find some other solution instead to fake the DateTime.Now and DateTime.UtcNow . I know all of this is pretty nasty, I am not the one who wrote and code, and I am not allowed to change it. I just have to write unit tests, but how - nobody cares :)

Comment: You'd need to know the details of *exactly* which methods `DateTime.ToUniversalTime` uses, and your tests would break if that changed over time. Urgh. This is why mocking is so brittle. I suggest you report all of this to whoever asked you to write the tests, and basically say that the code is untestable in any really sensible way. I mean, you could *assume* a particular system time zone, and just use sample values that you know about - get rid of the mocking entirely. But I don't like tests which only work in one time zone.

Comment: I will report it and will see what I can do. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You have to provide local and UTC DateTimeKind like this

```
Public Sub GetLocalTimeWithTimeDifferenceUTC_Test()
    Dim expected As String
    Dim actual As String
    Dim param As New System.DateTime(2015, 3, 5, 10, 0, 0)
    expected = "2015-03-05T10:00:00+03:00"
    Using (ShimsContext.Create())
        System.Fakes.ShimDateTime.NowGet = Function() As System.DateTime
                                               Return New DateTime(2015, 3, 5, 10, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local)
                                           End Function
        System.Fakes.ShimDateTime.UtcNowGet = Function() As System.DateTime
                                                  Return New DateTime(2015, 3, 5, 7, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
                                              End Function
        actual = StringFunctions.GetLocalStartTime(param)
    End Using
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual)
End Sub
```

Comment: No, that's not the problem here. (It's sort of *a* problem, but your solution won't immediately help the OP.) The problem is the code the OP is calling never uses the current date/time.